# Передача дополнительных параметров с формой

Tags: php, html, вёрстка, get, форма

Вечер добрый. Есть форма, которая заполняется пользователем и отправляется GET методом на нужный action. Форма передает параметры, которые ввел пользователь (username, vkid, about, неважно, главное, что их ввел пользователь через input). Но как вместе с формой послать доп. параметры, которые пользователь не видит и не может изменить?

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в форму

```
<input type="hidden" value="1234" name="name">
```

Answer (score 1):

**0.1.** Ваша схема клиент-серверного взаимодействия - не очень, потому что Вы делаете гет запросами то, что ими делать не надо. Конечно мир жив не restом единым, но Вы гарантированно поедите грязи меняя что-то гет запросами. С кешированием будут проблемы, со всякими ботами-краулерами-сканерами если API торчит наружу. Это только навскидку.

**0.2.** Параметров которые уходят на клиент и пользователь не может подменить на клиенте - не существует. Я надеюсь Вы помните об этом и не забываете о серверной валидации всего этого дела.

Ответ на основной вопрос зависит от природы данных которые Вы хотите посылать.

**1.** Если данные будут обрабатываться кучей вместе со всей остальной формой, то место им в теле запроса. И тогда можно сделать скрытый контрол на форме, как предложил Sergey Panasenko.

**2.** Если же это какая-то достаточно побочная форме информация то для этого существуют печеньки: [HTTP cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)